# Send/Receive in Outlook and close conection via code vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to send/receive all in outlook with VBA and after disconnect 
but `SendAndReceive()` and `SyncObject` don't notify when finished.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The SyncObject class provides the [SyncEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866270.aspx) event which is fired immediately after Microsoft Outlook finishes synchronizing a user’s folders using the specified Send/Receive group.